# Mongoose duplicate key error in nested schema

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have the following schema:

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const Comments = new Schema({
        authorId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            unique: false
        },
        commentBody: {
            type: String
        }
    });
    
    //Create schema
    const GroupSchema = new Schema({
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        comments: [Comments]
    });
    
    module.exports = Group = mongoose.model('group', GroupSchema);
```

I can insert the first group with no errors, but as soon as i try to add the second one i get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "MongoError",
        "message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: app-idiomas.groups index: comments.authorId_1 dup key: { : null }",
        "driver": true,
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: app-idiomas.groups index: comments.authorId_1 dup key: { : null }"
    }
}
```

So, as i suppose, the problem is with the "Comments" schema and i have searched about nested schema to see if i can solve this problem. I have tried to use "default" and "sparse" attribute, but no success.

Finally i decided to make a test and remove the Comments schema and it's reference in Groups Schema just to confirm that everything is OK. I erased all my database and added the first group (now without any comments attribute) and i still get the error whenever i try to add the second one. I just don't know why.

Any help ?

**UPDATE**

I didn't have time in these last days, but finally i found what the problem was. Probably when i was creating the Comments Schema i may have set the authorId to be unique and because of that MongoDB created an index for this attribute. I don't know much about MongoDB and that's why i hadn't checked before. But here is where i found the index and removed it:

[Location of "indexes" tab in MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lof4t.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has to be with record in the database.
But as you said you cleared the database, the problem looks weird.
Just make a check another time whether you deleted the correct database i.e the one you are using in your api.